# determine whether a list of vertices is a path through a graph

Tags: python-3.x, graph-theory, vertices

Given an input of a graph, and a list of vertices, is the list of vertices a path within the graph?

```
G = [['a', 'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'e' , 'f' , 'g' , 'h', 'i', 'j'],
     [({'a', 'b'}, 4), ({'a', 'c'}, 6), ({'a', 'd'}, 8), ({'b', 'e'}, 1) ,
      ({'b', 'f'}, 9), ({'c', 'f'}, 3), ({'d', 'g'}, 7), ({'d', 'h'}, 0) ,
      ({'e', 'i'}, 1), ({'e', 'j'}, 5), ({'g', 'h'}, 2), ({'i', 'j'}, 4)]]


L1 = ['a', 'd', 'h', 'g']
```

What would be the best way of tackling this problem?

Editː

This has now been solved - with Aimery's helpː

```
def edges(G):
    edgeset = [tuple(sorted(x[0])) for x in G[1]]
    return edgeset

def is_a_path(G,L,edgeset):
    for i in range(len(L)-1):
        a= tuple(sorted((L[i], L[i+1])))
        print(edgeset, a)
        if a not in edgeset:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: One straigth-forward way to do this is to check wether each part of your path is an actual edge in your graph.

Comment: considering the last 2 questions you posted revolved around the same topic and in none of them you posted any _code that you produced to try to solve the problem at hand_ ... you might want to reread [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You got some tips how to restructure your datastorage to make it easier on yourself. You can continue to present your problems a-piece-a-time to SO and let it be solved by the community but thats not really what SO is about - is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note:* I'll assume `G[0]`is the list of vertices, `G[1]` the list of (undirected) edges represented as `({<vertex tag>, <vertex tag>}, <weight>)`. Since you are using sets to represent edges, I assumed your graph is undirected.

First of all, you may want to check that all the elements in `L1` are vertices.

```
for candidate in L1:
    if not (candidate in G[0]]):
        # If it's not a vertex, we exit returning False
        return False
# If we're here, it means every candidate was a vertex
return True
```

Once this is done, you should check that the elements of `L1` are a path, that is, for every element of `L1` (except the last one), there exist an edge this element and the next one.

```
for i in range(len(L1)-1):
    # Create a candidate edge
    candidate = { L1[i], L1[i+1] }
    if not (candidate in G[0][:][0]):
        # If it's not in the list of edges, we exit returning False
        return False
# If every candidate edge is indeed an edge, then it's a path
return True
```